# How do you get Undertale trading cards?

Tags: undertale, steam-trading-cards

Undertale has 5 trading cards as far as I know. You get steam trading cards by playing the game or buying/trading for them usually from what I have heard/seen about them.

Flowey

Toriel

Papyrus

Undyne

The area you fall into at the start


I'm trying to collect them all but do not have money to buy any. I have Toriel, Flowey, and Papyrus by playing the game normally but have gone through 3 different runs (True pacifist, neutral, and genocide) and still don't have the other two (Undyne/The area you fall into). Does anybody know how to get those two cards without paying money?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only earn three trading cards by playing and purchasing Undertale, after that you would have to visit the Steam market or trade for them.

Comment: Welp that's sad, guess ima have to get money together then

Comment: @ChocolateChara They tend to cost just a few cents each. If you have trading cards for other games, you could sell those and use the "Steam wallet" cash to buy the cards you want.

Comment: I think I have a few cards I don't really care about, I could go and sell those.

Comment: This is answer is not quite complete; once you have received all card drops for a game you become eligible for a booster pack containing 3 more cards.

Comment: @MatthewJensen how would you get the pack?

Comment: @ChocolateChara - It just happens semi-randomly if you play.  See [this page](https://steamtradingcards.fandom.com/wiki/Booster_Packs) or the answer linked in the duplicate banner for what little is known of the mechanics.

Comment: Ah alright then, thanks.